# Error using sqlalchemy to create tables in postgresql

Tags: sqlalchemy

I am working with sqlalchemy (python 2.7) trying to create several tables in a postgresql (9.5) database. ubuntu 16.04

Using the abstraction of sqlalchemy I am having problems creating the tables with their primary and foreign keys for some reason.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Stacktrace and Error message and source code lastly:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "create_db.py", line 49, in <module>
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 3918, in create_all
    tables=tables)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1929, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1538, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 733, in visit_metadata
    _is_metadata_operation=True)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 767, in visit_table
    include_foreign_key_constraints=include_foreign_key_constraints
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1002, in _execute_ddl
    compiled
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/chris/workspace/final_project/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)

sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "filerecord"
 [SQL: '\nCREATE TABLE prodrecord (\n\tproductcode INTEGER NOT NULL, \n\tproductname VARCHAR(80), \n\tproductversion VARCHAR(80), \n\topsystemcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, \n\tmfgcode VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL, \n\tlanguage VARCHAR(80), \n\tapplicationtype VARCHAR(80), \n\tPRIMARY KEY (productcode, opsystemcode, mfgcode), \n\tUNIQUE (productcode, opsystemcode, mfgcode), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(productcode) REFERENCES filerecord (productcode), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(opsystemcode) REFERENCES osrecord (opsystemcode), \n\tFOREIGN KEY(mfgcode) REFERENCES mfgrecord (mfgcode)\n)\n\n']
```

create_db.py source

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.schema import UniqueConstraint


Base = declarative_base()

class FileRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'filerecord'
    sha1 = Column(String(80))
    md5 = Column(String(80))
    crc32 = Column(String(80))
    filename = Column(String(80))
    filesize = Column(Integer)
    productcode = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, unique=True)
    opsystemcode = Column(String(50))
    specialcode = Column(String(50))

class MfgRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mfgrecord'
    mfgcode = Column(String(80), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    mfgname = Column(String(80))

class OSRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'osrecord'
    opsystemcode = Column(String(80), primary_key=True, unique=True)
    opsystemname = Column(String(80))
    opsystemversion = Column(String(80))
    mfgcode = Column(String(80))

class ProdRecord(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'prodrecord'
    productcode = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('filerecord.productcode'), primary_key=True)
    productname = Column(String(80))
    productversion = Column(String(80))
    opsystemcode = Column(String(50), ForeignKey('osrecord.opsystemcode'), primary_key=True)
    mfgcode = Column(String(50), ForeignKey('mfgrecord.mfgcode'), primary_key=True)
    language = Column(String(80))
    applicationtype = Column(String(80))
    __table_args__ = (UniqueConstraint
                        (productcode, opsystemcode, mfgcode),)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db_string = "postgres://postgres:Drpepper1@localhost:5432/project"
    engine = create_engine(db_string)
    Base.metadata.create_all(engine)
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Perhaps you are not starting with a fresh database? (You possibly have an existing `filerecord` table in the db without a primary key or unique constraint on `productcode`.)

Comment: you are 100 percent right. Thanks. I dropped all the tables and ran again. Worked like a charm. Sorry for the question. Should have tried that before posting.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously @univerio's comment above solved the problem, but that solution is not valid in a production setting--where dropping all the tables is simply not an option. One of the popular (and incredibly powerful) ways of managing a database, and the accompanying migrations that follow, is by using [Alembic](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/alembic). It was written by the same guy who wrote SQLAlchemy, and I cannot recommend it enough. Here are a few more articles on that same topic:

https://www.compose.com/articles/schema-migrations-with-alembic-python-and-postgresql/
https://realpython.com/blog/python/flask-by-example-part-2-postgres-sqlalchemy-and-alembic/